# How to make the same projection as I did in G.Projection to QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

[image]

1. I didn't find the Azimuthal Equidistant(Two-Hemisphere) mode in QGIS, I just see the North_Pole_Azimuthal_Equidistant and South_Pole_Azimuthal_Equidistant in QGIS, does the QGIS support the two hemisphere mode?
2. I downloaded the map and make projection in QGIS, the map I got was not as the same distortation in G.Projection, and the G.Projection file is what I want. So how to operate in QGIS?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for Esri and do not use QGIS so my comments and suggests are based on what would work (or not) in ArcGIS software.

I suspect there is no Azimuthal Equidistant (Two-Hemisphere) mode in QGIS and you will have to emulate it with something like separate maps within a single layout or two separate maps. It looks like G.Projection is clipping at the equator for the two-hemisphere mode. In QGIS (and ArcGIS), you would need to clip the data layers at the equator before projecting them into azimuthal equidistant.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Would you please give more details about how to operate in Esri or QGIS?

Comment: @ThomasTeng I'm sorry--I've seen the results from other people so I know it's possible, not but don't it myself. In ArcGIS Desktop, there was a layout mode and you could insert two data frames (so each data frame would contain a hemisphere). I'm not sure how to do it in ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Would you please give the steps how to make in the ArcGIS? I installed the ArcGIS now